# Windows 10 App - start an other app or a native Windows application from within the app

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, windows-mobile

Is there a way to start another App or a native Windows Application like MS Word from within a Windows 10 App?
It's a JS Apache Cordova App running on a Windows 10 Tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - kinda and maybe but not like you'd think :)

You can use protocol activation (for example launching http://www.whatever.com and let the associated program handle it that is registered to handle http:// on the system - you can define your own protocols like fooAmI:// and have a desktop app handle that)

Then there's the more complicated route using brokered components

[How-to trigger a desktop process from sideloaded Windows Store Apps with Brokered Components](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmx/archive/2014/04/25/how-to-trigger-a-desktop-process-from-sideloaded-windows-store-apps-with-brokered-components.aspx)

There are some Win32 APIs available to WinRT apps but if you look under process management, there are no direct options for process control as this violates the sandbox like nature of WinRT apps.

[Win32 and COM API for Windows Runtime apps (System)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx#processes)